# Smysql Show results of first table whitch isnt in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, `images` and `articleImages`. In both tables is i_id column and now I need MySQL answer returns rows of images table which inst present in `articleImages` table too.

I trying something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM images,ArticleImages WHERE images.i_id!=ArticleImages.i_id
```

but its returns nothing and without `DISTINCT` element returns total nonsense

Comment: Please post sample data and the desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
NOT IN (...)

SELECT name
FROM images
WHERE images.i_id NOT IN (SELECT i_id FROM ArticleImages)
```

[MySQL Doco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: Please expand on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can join both tables using `LEFT JOIN`. What `LEFT JOIN` does is it returns all records on the *lefthand side* table which is `images` whether it has a matching record or not on the *righthand side* table which is `ArticleImages`. All the records that has no match wil have *NULL* values on the columns on table `ArticleImages` and this records are the one you want to be filtered.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    images a
        LEFT JOIN ArticleImages b
            ON a.i_id = b.i_id
WHERE   b.i_id IS NULL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)